# Unexpected behavior in Kotlin Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

I am having trouble in understanding the way `@Parcelize` working in Kotlin. According to documentations

> only the primary constructor properties will be serialized.

But when I serialize and deserialize classes with empty primary contractors, it is still serializing and deserializing all the fields. For example, below class

```
@Parcelize
class Node(): Parcelable {
    var field: String? = null
}
```

As primary contractor doesn't have any field, according to documentations I should have `field = null` always after ser/des. But whenever I run below codes

```
val before = Node()
before.field = "someField"

val bundle = Bundle().apply{ putParcelable("someKey", before) }
val after = bundle.getParcelable<Node>("someKey")
```

`field` is successfully serialized and deserialized and will have value of `someField`. 
Am I missing something or did `Parcelize` got updated but they didn't update documentation?

By the way if I leave Node declaration as above, Android Studio gives me warning that `field` will not be serialized into `Parcel`. But it is.

Comment: Are `val bundle` and `val after` executed in a row, in the same Activity/Fragment, or different ones?

Comment: @Onik in a same activity, it is run as above

Comment: So, there is no ser/des then. To get it ser/des you have to send an Intent.

Comment: Aren't putParcelable,getParcelable equivalent of ser/des?

Comment: I think, no. The system cannot know in advance how many params you'd put in a Bundle, so I believe ser happens before Binder transaction, i.e. upon Intent sending.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it in the constructor itself and it will work just fine.

```
@Parcelize
class Node( var field: String? = null) : Parcelable
```

And to use empty constructors in kotlin you can add this in app gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-noarg'
```

With this you can use classes with empty constructors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I know it works. My question is even if I don't put fields inside constructor it sill works